# Macro to count the number of text strings in sheet in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a worksheet for scoring.

I have a list in the first sheet that will be for data entry starting with a2 and going down the sheet, this is for Player names.

I have a summary sheet named "Place" that has a formula for pulling data.

I would like a macro to count the number of text strings in sheet "Setup" from A2 to whatever and then fill down sheet "Place" the correct number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
StringCount = 0

For i = 2 to range("A2").end(xldown).row 'assuming no breaks in data

If Typename(cells(i, 1).value) = "String" Then StringCount = StringCount + 1

Next i
```

This essentially gives you the number of strings in column A